# Name of anime with a scene where something is trapped in a wall

Tags: story-identification, anime

I recently saw the Beyblade movie. The Fierce battle scene in which Dragoon Beyblade or another Beyblades got trapped in stone wall, reminded me of a scene I saw long years ago with a similar trapped/sealed in wall moment.

It was like how a beast Beyblade spirit are sealed in stone wall. The other show with the same sort of thing, with something sealed or trapped in/turned into stone or a stone wall/monument. This happened after a creature (dragon?, monsters) died or disappeared.

The creatures are like Pokemon but big as the monster that got embedded in stone wall after they died.

What is the name of this show?

Comment: Close voters, note that if this is closed it gets returned to [anime.se].

Comment: see if anything here rings a bell: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TeleFrag